# thick and blue arrows

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows

I would like to create thick arrows as in this picture to connect the figure but I dont know how to make it on beamer. Any ideas please? 
[image]

Here is the code that I am using for tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
%       \includegraph777ics[height=6.5cm]{terre.png};
\node (fullwt) at (0,7){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{fullwt.png}};%

\node (hybrid1) at (3.5,5.5){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{hybrid1.png}};
%
\node (hybrid2) at (7,4){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{hybrid2.png}};
%
\node (fullpv) at (10.5,2.5){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{fullpv.png}};

\draw [>=latex, ->] (fullwt) {} (hybrid2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal, which is utilizes a further developed version of the `twisted arrow` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441860). The style definition is lengthy, but the benefit is that drawing the twisted arrow becomes then as simple as saying

```
\draw[twisted arrow={color=blue}] (A.east) to[bend left=50] (B.110);
```

The arrow will follow the specified path. Al(most al)l its parameters are stored in pgf keys, so you can adjust things.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{twisted arrow/.style={%
/utils/exec=\tikzset{twisted arrow/.cd,#1},
decorate,decoration={markings,%
mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (ta-base) at (0,0);},
mark=at position 0.02 with {\coordinate (ta-next) at (0,0);},
mark=at position 0.5 with {\coordinate (ta-mid) at (0,0);
\pgftransformreset
\filldraw[tacolor!80!black] let \p1=($(ta-next)-(ta-base)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
 ($(ta-base)+(\n1+90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/width}/2)$) 
    to[bend left=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/bend angle}/2] (ta-mid) 
    to[bend right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/bend angle}/2] 
 ($(ta-base)+(\n1-90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/width}/2)$) 
-- cycle;},
mark=at position 0.97 with {\coordinate (ta-near-end) at (0,0);},
mark=at position 0.99 with {\coordinate (ta-end) at (0,0);
\pgftransformreset
\filldraw[tacolor] let \p1=($(ta-end)-(ta-near-end)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
(ta-mid) to[bend left=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/bend angle}/2] 
($(ta-end)+(\n1+180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head length})
+(\n1+90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/width}/2)$)
-- ($(ta-end)+(\n1+180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head length})
+(\n1+90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head width}/2)$)
-- (ta-end) 
-- ($(ta-end)+(\n1+180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head length})
+(\n1-90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head width}/2)$)
--
($(ta-end)+(\n1+180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/head length})
+(\n1-90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/width}/2)$)
to[bend right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/twisted arrow/bend angle}/2] cycle;
}}},twisted arrow/.cd,width/.initial=6pt,
head length/.initial=6pt,
head width/.initial=10pt,
bend angle/.initial=45,
color/.code=\colorlet{tacolor}{#1},
color=gray}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Twisted arrows}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw=blue,thick}]
 \node (A) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node[below right=0em and 2em of A,anchor=north west] (B) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}};
 \node[below right=0.2em and 2.2em of B,anchor=north west] (C) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}};
 \node[below right=-0.4em and 2em of C,anchor=north west] (D) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
 %
 \draw[twisted arrow={color=blue}] (A.east) to[bend left=50] (B.110);
 \draw[twisted arrow={color=blue,bend angle=-45}] (B.-70) to[bend right=50] (C.west);
 \draw[twisted arrow={color=blue,}] (C.20) to[bend left=80] (D.110);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future, I would kindly like to ask you to provide complete documents, and also not to include graphics files which most users here won't have.